# JSON.stringify(list) shows an array of strings, however, Array.isArray(list) is false

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am currently trying to debug the issue in the title.

Here's some additional information:

- I am receiving the list from a DynamoDB set.
- JSON.stringify(list) prints: `["elt1","elt2"]`
- `Array.isArray(list) === false`
- list.map is undefined, list.forEach is undefined

```
const list2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(list))
Array.isArray(list2) === true
```

I have tried the above hack, and it does solve the issue- but it is definitely not conventional.

Comment: Console log the actual thing using `console.log({ list })`, open dev tools, and look at what object it _actually_ is. JSON.stringify has [a few rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description), find out which one's kicking in.

Comment: Can you share a [mre] of how `list` is generated? It's not really clear what type it even is; you haven't yet established how you reached the conclusion that it's affirmatively an `Array` to begin with.

Comment: Upon running `console.log(typeof list);`, it is actually an object.

Comment: @Tyler Of course; Arrays are of the Object type; see `console.log(typeof []);`. `console.log(list.constructor.name, list.constructor[Symbol.toStringTag], list.toJSON);` is much more useful.

Answer (score 2):

You've made an erroneous assumption: just because something produces an `Array` when run through `JSON.stringify()` does not necessarily mean it in itself is an `Array` to start. Consider this example:

```js
class MyClass {
  toJSON() {
    return ['a', 'b'];
  }
}

const list = new MyClass();

console.log(JSON.stringify(list));
console.log(Array.isArray(list));
console.log(list.map);
console.log(list.forEach);
```

In other words - it's entirely possible for a class to override the `toJSON()` method and fundamentally alter how it is processed by `JSON.stringify()`. I would suspect what you're encountering is that `list` is not really an `Array` (as you allude) but rather some other type that behaves this way when being stringified.

Answer (score -1):

It's return valid output (list.map is undefined, list.forEach is undefined),t because JSON.stringify() convert into a string and you can't apply any array function on in it.